# add() function with more parameters on solidity?

Tags: solidity, tokens, timelock

I'm trying to help a friend debug a timelocked transaction within a BSC smart contract written in solidity 0.6.12 but this is the first time I read code on this language and platform. We're trying to understand exactly what this queued transaction is doing. On BSC Scan we can see the signature says: add(uint256,address,uint16,bool)
I have decoded the 4 hex data to 2400, address, 400 and 0, but I don't understand what it means. From what I could get reading the smart contract, it seems add() takes only 2 arguments, and it's a sum using SafeMath library. What am I missing here? Thanks for any help!

```
library SafeMath {
function add(uint256 a, uint256 b) internal pure returns (uint256) {
    uint256 c = a + b;
    require(c >= a, 'SafeMath: addition overflow');

    return c;
}
```

Comment: Please link the smart contract you are referring to and also the transaction.

Comment: The add function with two parameters is internal and cannot be called from the outside. You need to locate a function with this signature `add(uint256,address,uint16,bool)`.